# Which odoo base method called for each creation , deletion, drag&drop action odoo9?

Tags: drag-and-drop, odoo-9

Which odoo base method called for each creation , deletion, drag&drop action? I know field_view_get called once refresh page.

Basically, I need method which is called on treeview table action. including all (CRUD, Drag and drop)

Answer (score 0):

when creating record

```
@api.model
def create(self, vals)
    ....
```

when updating or edit record

```
@api.multi
def write(self)
    ....
```

when delete or unlink record

```
@api.multi
def unlink(self)
    ....
```

name get for many2one field name

```
@api.multi
def name_get(self)
    ....
```